# FOR XML PATH is giving an error ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: sql, xml

The following sql query doesn't run as expected(generating an XML output) in oracle apex :-

```
SELECT CA_ID as "Address/CA_ID",
       ADDRESS_TYPE_ID as "Address/ADDRESS_TYPE_ID",
       ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE as "Address/ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE",
       ADDR1 as "Address/ADDR1",
       ADDR2 as "Address/ADDR2",
       CY_ID as "Address/CY_ID",
       COUNTRY as "Address/COUNTRY",
       CITY as "Address/CITY",
       STPR_ID as "Address/STPR_ID",
       STATE as "Address/STATE",
       POSTAL_CODE as "Address/POSTAL_CODE",
       DEFAULT_SUP_IND as "Address/DEFAULT_SUP_IND",
       APPRV_IND as "Address/APPRV_IND"    
from table(A1000_P310.GET_COMPANY_ADDRESS(8241,1))
FOR XML PATH('Addresses');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be because `FOR XML PATH` is not a valid Oracle syntax (but would work in MS SQL Server).

Is this what you are looking for? An example based on Scott's DEPT table:

```
SQL> select xmlelement("Dept", xmlforest(deptno, dname, loc)) result
  2  from dept;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Dept><DEPTNO>10</DEPTNO><DNAME>ACCOUNTING</DNAME><LOC>NEW YORK</LOC></Dept>
<Dept><DEPTNO>20</DEPTNO><DNAME>RESEARCH</DNAME><LOC>DALLAS</LOC></Dept>
<Dept><DEPTNO>30</DEPTNO><DNAME>SALES</DNAME><LOC>CHICAGO</LOC></Dept>
<Dept><DEPTNO>40</DEPTNO><DNAME>OPERATIONS</DNAME><LOC>BOSTON</LOC></Dept>

SQL>
```

If not, what would it be, then?